# Is there a way to search a Canvas element recursively in order to get buttons of a certain id?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

I am trying to access a canvas in html using JQuery in order to access every button that has the convention "_dummy" in it. This is for an exercise of learning how to traverse a Canvas element by writing a JQuery code that does it.

I was trying to base it off an earlier function I was using

```
function FindNestedObjectsAndDoStuff(obj)
{
    obj.children.forEach((subObj) => 
  {
    if (subObj.hasOwnProperty('children')
        && subObj.children instanceof Array
        && subObj.children.length > 0)
    {
        FindNestedObjectsAndDoStuff(subObj);
    }
    else
    {
      if (subObj.hasOwnProperty('parent')){
        var parentObject = subObj.parent;
        
        if (parentObject !== null){
            if (parentObject.name.includes("_dummy")){
                //TODO: Handle stuff here
            }
        }       
      }   
    }
  });
}
```

And I was happy to see that this it was working. I passed in an html element and it searched down form elements and div elements and found elements with the "_dummy". However, when I tried passing a Canvas object it doesn't work.  I see a message in the debug console window:

> AddCodeToElement.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: canvas.children.forEach is
> not a function

I since decided to create a new function, one that searches exclusively for Canvas elements:

```
function RegisterCanvasElementsAsBasicButtons(canvas)
{
    canvas.each(function(index, element) 
  {
    if (element.hasOwnProperty('children')
        && element.children instanceof Array
        && element.children.length > 0)
    {
        RegisterNestedMovieClipObjects(element);
    }
    else
    {
      if (element.hasOwnProperty('parent')){
        var parentObject = element.parent;
        
        if (parentObject !== null){
            if (parentObject.name.includes("_dummy")){
                RegisterMovieClipAsBasicButton(parentObject);
            }
        }       
      }   
    }
  });
}
```

This one doesn't show me the error anymore but I'm not sure if this is the right way to traverse the Canvas elements or not. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? How can I modify my code in order to make my function iterate a Canvas element in order to find what I'm looking for?

Comment: Canvas children do not usually display, they're meant as a fallback in the event canvas isn't supported. You're either seeing other elements overlayed on the canvas (that are not children of the canvas) or you are seeing drawings on the canvas (that are not elements).

Comment: @Ouroborus I see. So I I was querying the wrong element. Sorry about that. I'm still learning the ins and outs. Thank you